# Why is the true positive - false negative distribution always the same

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I have a neural network that I use it for binary classification. I change the size of training data and predict on the test set. By looking at the results, the difference between `tp` and `fn` is always the same and the difference between `tn` and `fp` is always the same. For example, in iteration #2, `tp#2 - tp#1 = -91` and `fn#2 - fn#1 = +91`. Also, `fp#2 - fp#1 = -46` and `tn#2 - tn#1 = +46`. As another example, `tp#3 - tp#2 = -35` and `fn#2 - fn#2 = +35`.

```
Iteration #1
tn=119, fp=173, fn=110, tp=407
Iteration #2
tn=165, fp=127, fn=201, tp=316
Iteration #3
tn=176, fp=116, fn=236, tp=281
Iteration #4
tn=157, fp=135, fn=207, tp=310
Iteration #5
tn=155, fp=137, fn=214, tp=303
```

I have tried various architectures of neural nets, but I always get the same numbers. Do you have an idea what is wrong.

The following is a very simple network that I use:

```py
class AllCnns(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_size):
        torch.manual_seed(0)
        super(AllCnns, self).__init__()
        self.word_embeddings = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_size)
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(embedding_size, 64, 3)
        self.drop1 = nn.Dropout(0.3)
        self.max_pool1 = nn.MaxPool1d(2)
        self.flat1 = nn.Flatten()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64*80, 100)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(100, 1)

    def forward(self, sentence):
        embedding = self.word_embeddings(sentence).permute(0, 2, 1)
        conv1 = F.relu(self.conv1(embedding))
        drop1 = self.drop1(conv1)
        max_pool1 = self.max_pool1(drop1)
        flat1 = self.flat1(max_pool1)
        fc1 = F.relu(self.fc1(flat1))
        fc2 = torch.sigmoid(self.fc2(fc1))
        return fc2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be the same.
The sum of tn(true negative) and fp(false positive) adds up to the total 'real' negative values, and same goes for the other two.
So as long as you are using the same data,

```
tn + fp = 292(total negative values)
fn + tp = 517(total positive values)
```

these equations are always true.
So `tn#1 + fp#1 = tn#2 + fp#2` so `tn#1 - tn#2 = fp#2 - fp#1`